# Unable to reselect single item in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a listview in WPF in an MVVM/PRISM app which may contain 1-to-many elements.  When the listview contains only 1 element, and I select it, I cannot subsequently reselect it even though I set the SelectedIndedx value to -1.  Worse, if I make the app update the listview with a different single element, I can't select that one either.  The only way I can achieve selection of an item when it is the only item in the listview is to make the app display multiple items and select something other than the first.  Then, when I make the app display a listview containing a single item, I can select it again - but only once.

In those cases where I cannot select the single item in the listview, the servicing routine never fires.

I tried implementing a XAML suggestion I found here using "Listview.Container.Style"  and the IsSelected property, but that did not work.

My listview is fairly straightforward:

```
    <ListView Name="lstEditInstance"
          Grid.Row="5"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InstanceList,Mode=TwoWay}"
          Width="488"
          FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    
          Margin="10,96,0,28"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=InstanceSelectedIndex}">
    </ListView>
```

The servicing routine is:

```
    private void OnInstanceSelectedIndexChanged()
    {
      // Handle case where user hits Enter without making a selection:

      if (_instanceIndex == -1) return;

      // Get the instance record for the row the user clicked on as a
      // ResourceInstance class named "InstanceRecord".  

      InstanceRecord = _instanceList[_instanceIndex];

      _instanceNumber     = InstanceRecord.Instance;
      FormInstName        = InstanceRecord.InstName;
      FormInstEnabled     = InstanceRecord.Enabled;
      FormInstState       = InstanceRecord.InitialState;
      FormInstIPAddress   = InstanceRecord.IPAddress;
      FormInstPort        = InstanceRecord.Port.ToString();
      FormInstSelectedURL = InstanceRecord.UrlHandler;

    } // End of "OnResourceSelectedIndexChanged" method.
```

"InstanceList" is an observable collection.

I'd appreciate some suggestions.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In a MVVM scenario, I'd use a ViewModel that contains the selected item instead:

```
class MyViewModel {

private IList<Item> instanceList= new List<Item>();

public IList<Item> List
{
    get {return list; }
    set {
        list = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => List);
    }
}

private Item selectedItem;

public Item SelectedItem {
    get {return selectedItem;}
    set {
        selectedItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
    }
}}
```

And the XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lstEditInstance"
  Grid.Row="5"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InstanceList}"
  Width="488"
  FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11"
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    
  Margin="10,96,0,28"
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}}">
```

Notice that observableCollection is not required unless you have to modify the list items, in the same way the binding should be the default one for the list.
The SelectedItem / SelectedIndex should be TwoWay or Onewaytosource, the latter if you think you don't need to change the selectedItem programmatically
The service routine should be called from the ViewModel

EDIT:

your code of the service routine should be placed there:

```
set {
    selectedItem = value;
    // your code
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
}
```

Another valid approach is to use Blend on XAML, by invoking a command on changed index and process under the ViewModel.

To do this, first add reference to System.Windows.Interactivity in your project and in XAML add 
 xmlns:interactivity="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity

Then modify ListView with the following:

```
<ListView Name="lstEditInstance"
Grid.Row="5"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InstanceList}"
Width="488"
FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    
Margin="10,96,0,28"
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}}">
<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
<interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
  <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommand}"
                         CommandParameter="{Binding YourCommandParameter}" />
</interactivity:EventTrigger>
</interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: To user3042207: the servicing routine is in a viewmodel, and the selected index is a property.  My apologies for not making this clear.